# Mysql-client cannot connect new ip

Tags: mysql

Mysql client is behaving strangely on one of my servers.

I have my mysql server (ip 10.0.0.190, used to be 172.16.0.190).
I have another server from which I try to connect, which I will refer to as `collab`.

Bind address is set to `0.0.0.0` server-side, as well as the Grant options for `collab`.

When I try to connect through `mysql-client`, here is what I do :

```
> mysql -u user -p -h mysql.domain
```

This doesn't work, and after 30s I get this error message :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.domain' (110)
```

Now the weird thing is that if I do :

```
> mysql -u user -p -h 10.0.0.190
```

Everything works correctly. At first, I thought it was a DNS issue, so I tried ping, dig which all answered properly. ie, from client :

```
> ping mysql.domain
64 bytes from mysql.domain (10.0.0.190): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.999 ms
```

So I launched `tcpdump` on both the server and the client. On the server I get nothing.

On the client :

```
> tcpdump port 3306
[ ... ]
11:11:41.139499 IP client.domain.49186 > 172.16.0.190.mysql
[ ... ]
```

As I said, `172.16.0.190` used to be the `client`'s IP before I switched my network. I understand this is where the error comes from, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Obviously the error comes from the `collab` but I can't figure out where does it comes from. I've tried to grep '172.16.0' in my /etc on `collab` in case I had forgotten anything, but nothing came back.

Moreover, when I try to connect from another server using the FQDM, it works.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks,
Cheers
H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be a DNS cache issue.  Try flushing your cache.  If you are on windows/osx, look at this: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/ClearingBrowserCache

I'm not sure what has to be done on Linux.

(Flush on CLIENT side, by the way).

Comment: I'm not really sure how DNS caches work, but I know what they do and that they exist.  If information is cached on an application-based system, then maybe your info for just mysql is wrong

Comment: Indeed. I used : service nscd restart to reload the client cache. I would have never guessed that ping / mysql used a different cache system. Otherwise it wouldn't have worked correctly for the ping. But thanks a lot !